# How can I Add value of Multiple TextBox and Display In another TextBoChanged Property

Tags: vb.net

[image]Here I am coding in VB.NET where i am designing some FEESMODULE where I am ENTERING value for TEXTBOX like PROSPACTUS, REGISTRATION, TUTION AND EXAM and want when i am entering THESE valueS, at that point of time value also should be added together in TEXTBOX named TOTAL. I tried codes Are below but i am getting wrong answer[image]

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


    TextBox8.Text = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged


    TextBox8.Text =  Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text) + Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

    TextBox8.Text =  Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text) + Integer.Parse(TextBox3.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged

    TextBox8.Text =  Integer.Parse(TextBox8.Text) + Integer.Parse(TextBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you entering, what are you expecting, and what are you getting?  Do favor Integer.TryParse over Integer.Parse.

Comment: see i add one pic where i am entering 100 and another 500 the  result should be 600 but i am getting 655

Comment: Think of the logic with the TextChanged event.  When you press "5" you add 5, so 105.  You press "0", you get "50", now you add 50 and get 155.  Press "0", you get "500", so now it's 655.  Don't use the number you have in TextBox8, just add the numbers from the input boxes.

Comment: Why are you not using NumericUpDown controls?

Comment: Here is what is happening. The `TextChanged` event fires each time the text property changes; that means whenever a character is added or removed. When you start typing in the second text box the first time the event fires there is just a 5 in the box so the total `TextBox` will show 105. You type the second digit and the total will be 105 + 50 or 155. You type the third digit and finally the total is 155 +500 or 655. This is happening so fast as you type, that you do not see it changing. Obviously this is the wrong event to use. Try the Leave event with .TryParse

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your form load event. You will have to adjust your group names, and/or include other groups into the routines. This is not a drop in solution, but I put it in a way you should be able to easily deduct your solution. You should really be using numeric type control such as NumericUpDown.

```
    'Use the parent control collection to add handles
    For Each TxBx As TextBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
        AddHandler TxBx.KeyDown, Sub(s As TextBox, ex As KeyEventArgs)

                                     'at least limit to numeric keys, include backspace,selete and minus
                                     Dim AllowedKeys() As Integer = {49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48,
                                     189, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 96, 109, 8, 46}

                                     If Not AllowedKeys.Contains(ex.KeyData) Then
                                         ex.SuppressKeyPress = True
                                     End If

                                 End Sub

        AddHandler TxBx.KeyUp, Sub(s As TextBox, ex As KeyEventArgs)
                                   'Sum your madness
                                   Dim Tot As Integer = 0
                                   For Each Tb As TextBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)
                                       Dim ChkInt As Integer
                                       Integer.TryParse(Tb.Text, ChkInt)
                                       Tot += ChkInt
                                   Next
                                   TxBxTotal.Text = Tot.ToString
                               End Sub

    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

It is quite unclear of what you are trying to do. My guess it updating TextBox8 every time others get new values. Try this:

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged,TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox4.TextChanged


    TextBox8.Text = SumValues()
   'Label12.Text = a - Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Function SumValues() As Integer

    Dim Total As Integer = 0
    Total += IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text), 0, Val(TextBox1.Text)) + _
IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text), 0, Val(TextBox2.Text)) + _
IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox3.Text), 0, Val(TextBox3.Text)) + _
IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text), 0, Val(TextBox4.Text))

    Return Total
```

There are more efficient way to do it, lol, but this is how I'd do it. Plain and simple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193169/discussion-on-answer-by-weight-how-can-i-add-value-of-multiple-textbox-and-displ).